# Is it possible to make a warped/distorted choropleth in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Choropleths are useful, but they can be misleading if they don't account for population density, for example see the images below:

[image]

[image]

Is is possible to warp/distort Highcharts `mapChart`s according to some value, and make plots like the ones above? Ideally with GeoJSON source data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such possibility in Highcharts to distort maps. Only you can create your own custom one and use it.

**Docs**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps